# There are no automatic redirection with paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

Tags: laravel-5, paypal-sandbox

Implementing paypal in my laravel 5.8 app

Looking at the code snippet :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/integrate/?mark=get%20the%20code#set-up-your-development-environment

I do not seer which is returns valid format?

here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/#create-paypal-payment
I found that redirect_urls must be used , so my button definition is :

```
                    <script>
                        paypal.Button.render({
                            // Configure environment
                            env: 'sandbox',
                            client: {
                                sandbox: 'CLIENTID',
                                production: 'demo_production_client_id'
                            },
                            // Customize button (optional)
                            locale: 'en_US',
                            style: {
                                size: 'small',
                                color: 'blue',
                                shape: 'pill',
                            },

                            commit: true,

                            payment: function(data, actions) {
                                return actions.payment.create({

                                    "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",

                                    "intent": "sale",
                                    "payer": {
                                        "payment_method": "paypal"
                                    },

                                    redirect_urls : { //redirect_urls
                                        return_url : 'https://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/paypal_payment',
                                        cancel_url : 'https://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/paypal_payment_cancel'
                                    },

                                    transactions: [{
                                        amount: {
                                            total: '0.01',
                                            currency: 'USD'
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });
                            },
                            // Execute the payment
                            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                                console.log("onAuthorize data::")
                                console.log( data )

                                console.log("onAuthorize actions::")
                                console.log( actions )

                                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                                    // Show a confirmation message to the buyer

                                    window.alert('Thank you for your purchase! 0');
                                });
                            }
                        }, '#paypal-button');

                    </script>
```

I see alert in actions.payment.execute method, but no automatic rederection at url specified in return_url, as I expected.
I uploaded my site live at https://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk under LAMP, Ubuntu 18 , Digital Ocean.
Why there are no automatic redirection ?

```
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.8.24

In composer.json:
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
```

**MODIFIED :** 
I remade in way when payment var created and returned a :

```
                            payment: function(data, actions) {
                                var payment = actions.payment.create({

                                    "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",

                                    "intent": "sale",
                                    "payer": {
                                        "payment_method": "paypal"
                                    },

                                    redirect_urls : { //redirect_urls
                                        return_url : 'https://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/paypal_payment',
                                        cancel_url : 'https://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/paypal_payment_cancel'
                                    },

                                    transactions: [{
                                        amount: {
                                            total: '0.01',
                                            currency: 'USD'
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });

                                console.log("payment payment::")
                                console.log(payment);
                                // alert( "::"+var_dump(-88) )
                                return payment;

                            },
```

and noteced warnings :

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/app/123?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false. app.js:1767:16
The connection to wss://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/app/123?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

printscreen with console payment output and and error messages looks like :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gqf7.jpg

What raised these errors ?

Comment: Could you please look at paypal with sanbox at my site live :
open https://www.votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/test and click https://prnt.sc/oaejzc
I see “Thank you for your purchase!” message and no any redirect. Can it be issue of my paypal app some options missed
or account I login into the app ?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED block